# Change Navigation Bar Item Dynamically - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I am creating a `NavigationBar` with `UIBarButtonItem` which located on right side of screen. As default I set that `setRightBarButton` with `UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "edit"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(editProfile))` and when I clicked on that it should change that `rightBarButton` to other title but it doesn't work.

Here is I tried to change with I clicked on it

```
@objc
func editProfile() {
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(cancelActionBar, animated: true)

}
```

This is object of `cancelActionBar`

```
let cancelActionBar = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelEdit))
```

And this is its action which change it back to default.

```
@objc
func cancelEdit() {
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(editActionBar, animated: true)
}
```

I also tried to use main thread as well but it is not working as I expected.

Comment: It is not working at all? did you try to set breakpoints? is `editProfile` called?

Comment: @Lu_ Of course it is not working because I declared it outside `viewdidload()`. Now it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a `UIBarButtonItem` as instance property the target `self` won't be initialized yet. So setting the target `self` won't work.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let editActionBar = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(editBtnAction(_:)))
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(editActionBar.target)//nil
    }
}
```

The target `self` will be assigned properly when you initialize the button in `viewDidLoad`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var editActionBar: UIBarButtonItem?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        editActionBar = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(editBtnAction(_:)))
        print(editActionBar?.target)//self
    }
}
```

---

Declare the buttons as optional and initialize the buttons in viewDidLoad.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var editActionBar: UIBarButtonItem?
    var cancelActionBar: UIBarButtonItem?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.editActionBar = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(editBtnAction(_:)))
        self.cancelActionBar = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelBtnAction(_:)))
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(editActionBar, animated: true)
    }
    @objc func editBtnAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(cancelActionBar, animated: true)
    }
    @objc func cancelBtnAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(editActionBar, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right. I didn't initialized in `viewDidLoad()` I just declared it outside the `viewdidload()`. now it is working..

Answer (score 1):

In viewDidLoad method set edit as bar button

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
      self.setBarButton(isSetEditBarButton: true)
}

@objc func editProfile() {
    self.setBarButton(isSetEditBarButton: false)
}


@objc func cancelEdit() {
    self.setBarButton(isSetEditBarButton: true)
}


 private func setBarButton(isSetEditBarButton: Bool) {
     if isSetEditBarButton {
           let editActionBar = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "edit"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(editProfile))
           self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(editActionBar, animated: true)
     } else {
           let cancelActionBar = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelEdit))
           self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(cancelActionBar, animated: true)
     }
   }
```